# React automatically change the first letter of property to uppercase only when is running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-props

I'm trying to show a list of authors and comments with this code:

```
class CommentBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }
  loadCommentsFromServer() {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("get", this.props.url, true);
    xhr.onload = () => {
      const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      this.setState({ data: data });
    };
    xhr.send();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
    window.setInterval(
      () => this.loadCommentsFromServer(),
      this.props.pollInterval
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
        <CommentForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class CommentList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const commentNodes = this.props.data.map(comment => (
      <Comment key={comment.id} author={comment.author}>
        {comment.text}
      </Comment>
    ));
    return (
      <div className="commentList" key={comment.id}>
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class CommentForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="commentForm" />;
  }
}

class Comment extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">{this.props.author}</h2>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox url="/comments" pollInterval={2000} />,
  document.getElementById("content")
);
```

This is my jsx file and the problem appears when I run the application, at the browser my comment.id becomes comment.Id, as all the other attributes of my object, and he can't get any property. I'm really out of options, I've already changed my model to lowercase, but the problem persist. I've already changed the properties declaration at my mode, changed my controller and even the jsx file.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your ajax return json data?

Comment: i.e., console log of this.state.data in CommentBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line `this.loadCommentsFromServer = this.loadCommentsFromServer.bind(this)` into your constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { data: [] };
   this.loadCommentsFromServer = this.loadCommentsFromServer.bind(this)
}
```

According to the [Official React Document](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), they said:

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.
>
> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions
>   work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without ()
>   after it, such as onClick={this.handleClick}, you should bind that
>   method.

Inside the `loadCommentsFromServer()` method, you did use the `this` variable in order to update the component state. Hence, if you don't bind it, the value of `this` at the moment `loadCommentsFromServer()` method is invoked won't be the component, it is `undefined`. Consequently, we cannot update the component state.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping It works! Could you explain why this solved the problem?
Edit here: Now i saw your explanation, again thanks for helping and thanks for explain the reason

Comment: or you can use arrow functions ;)
You don't need to bind the function in the constructor.

change your loadCommentsFromServer function to an arrow one ```loadCommentsFromServer = () => { /* server call here */ }```

Answer (score 0):

check your response data receiving in **loadCommentsFromServer()**